# Segmentation fault (recursion never ending) in C

Tags: c, recursion, backtracking, maze

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Given a Maze, it desired to find a path from a given starting position to the location with cheese (target
>   position). Maze is visualized as a rectangular grid containing walls (represented as 1) or free ways
>   (represented as 0). The program must print a path that starts from starting location to the ending location.
>   The target location will have value 9 stored in it. In this program, it is assumed that cyclic paths are not
>   possible in the grid. (You need not check for cyclic paths.)

This is what I am doing:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct Maze
{
    int ** values;
    int size;
} Maze;

int traverse (Maze M, int n, int posi, int posj, char **path_so_far,
        int past_i, int past_j)
{
    int k;
    printf("Hello\n");
    int i=0;
    int temp;  

    if (M.values[posi][posj] == 9)
    {
        path_so_far[i][0] = posi + '0';
        path_so_far[i][1] = posj + '0';
        path_so_far[i][2] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", path_so_far[i]); 
        i++;
        return 1;    
    }
    else if (posi - 1 >= 0 && M.values[posi - 1][posj] != 1
            && posi - 1 != past_i)
    {      
        temp = traverse(M, n, posi - 1, posj, path_so_far, past_i, past_j);
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            path_so_far[i][0] = posi + '0';
            path_so_far[i][1] = posj + '0';
            path_so_far[i][2] = '\0';      
            printf("%s\n", path_so_far[i]);               
            i++;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else if (posi + 1 < n && M.values[posi + 1][posj] != 1 && posi + 1 != past_i)
    {
        temp = traverse(M, n, posi + 1, posj, path_so_far, past_i, past_j);
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            path_so_far[i][0]=posi+'0';
            path_so_far[i][1]=posj+'0';
            path_so_far[i][2]='\0';  
            printf("%s\n",path_so_far[i]);                    
            i++;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else if(posj - 1 >=0 && M.values[posi][posj - 1] !=1 && posj - 1 != past_j)
    { 
        temp = traverse(M, n, posi, posj - 1, path_so_far, past_i, past_j);
        if(temp==1)
        {
            path_so_far[i][0] = posi + '0';
            path_so_far[i][1] = posj + '0';
            path_so_far[i][2] = '\0';   
            printf("%s\n", path_so_far[i]);                  
            i++;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else if (posj + 1 < n && M.values[posi][posj + 1] != 1 && posj + 1 != past_j)
    { 
        temp = traverse(M, n, posi, posj + 1, path_so_far, past_i, past_j);
        if(temp == 1)
        {
            path_so_far[i][0] = posi + '0';
            path_so_far[i][1] = posj + '0';
            path_so_far[i][2] = '\0';     
            printf("%s\n", path_so_far[i]);                   
            i++;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }                     
}
```

Maze M has been taken care of i.e. it is initialized in another function, which is not shown here.  I am calling `traverse` with arguments `(M, 0, 0, 0, path, 0, 0)`, but it produces a segmentation fault.  I tried adding `printf("Hello\n")`, as shown in 10th line of my code, to see where the error occurs; it prints "Hello" large number of times, and finally gives `segmentation fault`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Putting several statements in one line makes code very hard to follow.

Comment: Can you post the code of the function in which you're calling `traverse`

Comment: Especially if they are supposed to be inside `if` block, but not surrounded with `{}`...

Comment: You should learn to use debugger before starting to write code of that complexity. Setting breakpoints, watching variables, watching call stack: you cannot make any non-trivial correct program without it in decent time. Take a course of software engineering methods in your university or pick a book or at least find some videos about it on youtube. This will help you A LOT.

Comment: If you look closer at the `i` variable, you'll find out you use a new `i` on each `traverse` call, which always starts from `0` and never goes farther than to `1`...

Comment: @RSahu Sorry for my earlier code.I have editted it and its now more readable.

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks that was a mistake,but still it is giving the same error

Comment: @Coder Are you aware, that after the edit the code is different from the original one (the if blocks..)?

Comment: Yes I know and I am sorry I posted the wrong code above earlier.I have run this new code and still it is giving me the same error i.e. printing `Hello` many times and finally `segmentation fault`.

Comment: @Coder,Please post the function that sets up the maze before calling `traverse`.

Comment: @RSahu I have editted my question and added the function that sets up the maze.But as  I said it is correct I have tried printing the Maze in `traverse` and it gives the correct values.

Comment: @Coder, Since you have already accepted an answer, I assumed your questions are answered and your program runs fine now. Good luck with the next programming project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using parameters `past_i` and `past_j` to avoid doubling back, but when you recurse, you do not pass the coordinates of the previous position as is required for such a scheme to be effective.   For example, it appears that this ...

```
temp = traverse(M, n, posi - 1, posj, path_so_far, past_i, past_j);
```

... should be ...

```
temp = traverse(M, n, posi - 1, posj, path_so_far, posi, posj);
```

.  Without doing this, you can (and do) get stuck going back and forth between two positions (looks like probably between 0,1 and 1,1).  There are other problems with your code, such as not correctly recording the path, but the segmentation fault probably results from recursing deeply enough to exhaust your stack space.

Comment: Thanks a lot.A silly mistake,but recursion is something which is quite difficult to debig.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

There are some important mistakes in your code design. One of them is the `i` variable use (see my comment). Another is an approach to printing a path step: first, it's wrong to print the i-th step *after* you return from recursive `traverse` (because all later steps were already printed inside the recursion!); however you also can't print it *before* the recursion (because you don't know if you're on the right path). So, how to do that?

Well, you should mark a next step you will take in a `path_so_far[i]` and then step into a recursion. You also need to pass an incremented step number `i+1` to the recursive step, so that the function always knows which step it is performing, and which item of `path_so_far` it should fill.

When you reach a target point you just print the whole accumulated `path_so_far`, which at the moment is a final path, then return `1` for success. This result percolates up the recursion eventually causing end of calculation.

On the other hand if you find you have no further move possible you return `0` for failure. This result of recursive `traverse` should cause you to test another possibility at the current level.

So:

```
int traverse(Maze M, int n, int posi, int posj,char **path_so_far, int i)
{
    int temp;
    if(M.values[posi][posj]==9)  // target found
    {
        int j;                   // print the complete path
        for(j=0; j<i; j++)
            printf("%s\n",path_so_far[j]);
        return 1;
    }

    // mark the current position as 'visited'

    M.values[posi][posj] = 2;

    // try next possible move
    // test if adjacent cell is empty or is target

    if(posi-1>=0 && (M.values[posi-1][posj]==0 || M.values[posi-1][posj]==9))
    {      
        path_so_far[i][0]=posi-1+'0';
        path_so_far[i][1]=posj+'0';
        path_so_far[i][2]='\0';      
        temp=traverse(M,n,posi-1,posj,path_so_far,i+1);
        if(temp==1)
            return 1;
    }

    if(posi+1<n && (M.values[posi+1][posj]==0 || M.values[posi+1][posj]==9))
    {      
        path_so_far[i][0]=posi+1+'0';
        path_so_far[i][1]=posj+'0';
        path_so_far[i][2]='\0';      
        temp=traverse(M,n,posi+1,posj,path_so_far,i+1);
        if(temp==1)
            return 1;
     }

     // similary for posj-1 and posj+1...

    if(posj-1>=0 && (M.values[posi][posj-1]==0 || M.values[posi][posj-1]==9))
    {
        ...
    }

    if(posj+1<n && (M.values[posi][posj+1]==0 || M.values[posi][posj+1]==9))
    {
        ...
    }

    // none of the tested paths returned success...
    // mark the current position as no longer 'visited'

    M.values[posi][posj] = 0;

    //return the failure status

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all paths in `traverse()` return a value. Every code block that contains

```
if(temp == 1)
    {
    ...
    return 1;
    }
```

will fail to return *any* function value, when

```
(temp != 1)
```

You must have all warnings enabled on your compiler... especially when things are not working.

Comment: Thanks but the above anwer fixed the problem.It seems I was not updating the `past_i` and `past_j `values.

Comment: You still must fix the return values, and don't forget that old adage *"there is always one more bug"*..

Comment: Yeah this also seems to be a problem in my code.Thanks again.